# Sinon: Stub and entire object and replace it with a new object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

Using Sinon, how does one stub an entire object and all of its methods and then replace them with another object?

I have tried something like this, but it doesnt seem to work:

```
var stubby = sinon.stub(stubbedObj);
stubby.returns(newReplacementObj);

console.log(stubby); // this returns stub, but it would think that it should return newReplacementObj?
```

Comment: https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire Take a look at that. Sounds like that would suit your needs better.

Comment: You should use sinon [mocks](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#mocks).

Comment: Your sentence is unclear. You cannot stub methods and replace them with an object. You can stub all methods of an object, though `sinon.stub(anObject)` will definitely return `anObject` no special stub object. In your case `stubbedObj === stubby` is `true`. So unless you have `returns` in it there's no such method. Though each stubbed method (which is a stub) has a `returns` method that might be used to return anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider refactoring your code to call a function that you can then stub instead.  Example instead of stubbing out window.something, you can make an accessor method that uses window.something, and then stub out that accessor method.